# How to patch function inside a parametrized fixture?

Tags: python, python-3.6, pytest, fixtures, monkeypatching

I would like to patch a function depending of the environment thus considering we have environnement `mode1` and `mode2` .

With the code below monkeypatch call always the function patched from `mode1`

If I switch the param order  `mode2` and `mode1` it will call always the function patched from `mode2`.

But I would like to use the function pacthed dependeing of the requested param.

I checked using the debugger both condtion checking the mode: `mode1` and `mode2` works and set as expected the right function. But allways it keep the first function patched.

conftest.py

```
def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
  if 'patch_fhs' in metafunc.fixturenames:
    metafunc.parametrize('patch_fhs', ['mode1', 'mode2'], indirect=True, scope='session')


@pytest.fixture()
def parametrized_patch(request):
  if request.param == 'mode1':
    monkeypatch = MonkeyPatch()
    import mymodule
    def patched_func():
      return 'patched_mode1'
    monkeypatch.setattr(mymodule, 'my_func', patched_func)
  elif if request.param == 'mode2':
    monkeypatch = MonkeyPatch()
    import mymodule
    def patched_func():
      return 'patched_mode2'
    monkeypatch.setattr(mymodule, 'my_func', patched_func)
  else:
    raise ValueError('Unknown mode named: {name}'.format(name=request.param))
  return request.param
```

test_parametrized_fixture.py

```
def test_foo(parametrized_patch):
 from mymodule import my_func
 print(parametrized_patch)
 print(my_func)
```

The tests ouptput will be something like

```
-> test_foo
mode1
patched_mode1
-> test_foo
mode2
patched_mode1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@pytest.fixture(params=your_params)
def parametrized_patch(monkeypatch, request):
    monkey patch.setattr(
        your_module,
        'your_func',
        lambda x, y, z: request.param
    )
```

x, y, z are the arguments the function you are trying to patch will take

Comment: Thanks @ishan Joshi we have made a minimal example with your snippet and that works so now we have to works on our code in order to get a better understanding. I upvoted your answer